# How to match the empty space at the end of line as preceding sentence

Tags: regex

Hi I have got this regex that matches sentences but I need to match the empty space between them as well.

```
(((?![.\n\s])[^.\n]*(?:"[^\n"]*[^\n".]"[^.\n"]*)*(?:"[^"\n]+\?"|\."|\!"|\.)))
```

Any help would be awesome.

Sample data

> hi how are you", sasasasas.   whats going on, "sasasas?" "It's amazing
>   when you think of it," said Adell. His broad face had lines of
>   weariness in it, and he stirred his drink slowly with a glass rod,
>   watching the cubes of ice slur clumsily about.  "It was Adell's turn
>   to be contrary. "Maybe we can build things up again someday," he said.
>   "No bet," whispered Lupov. They left hurriedly.  "You ask Multivac. I
>   dare you. Five dollars says it can't be done."  "Quiet, children,"
>   said Jerrodine sharply. "Are you sure, Jerrodd?"  "A hundred billion
>   is not infinite and it's getting less infinite all the time. Consider!
>   Twenty thousand years ago, mankind first solved the problem of
>   utilizing stellar energy, and a few centuries later, interstellar
>   travel became possible. It took mankind a million years to fill one
>   small world and then only fifteen thousand years to fill the rest of
>   the Galaxy. Now the population doubles every ten years ."

It matches the sentences properly. I just need empty space to be matched as part of the sentence.

I am using https://regexr.com

Comment: How do you want to match that space? As part of the preceding sentence? As part of the following sentence? Or some other way? Also, you need to include your regex and an example of how it isn't working here, not just a link. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Edited my post.

Comment: Replace the ending `))` with `\s*))`